# Get dicts from array of dictionaries with the same value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries (example here):

```
data = [
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Doe",
    "country" : [ "England" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Smith",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Foo",
    "country" : [ "England", "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Bar",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  }
]
```

I need the output to be sorted, and filtered by the country and as a string:

```
England: John Doe, John Foo
Germany: Jane Bar, John Foo, Jane Smith
```

Right now, I have only figured out to find the unique countries:

```
values_from_country = [a_dict['country'] for a_dict in data]
unique_country = set([x for l in values_from_aff for x in l])
>>> output {'England', 'Germany'}
```

Can you guys help me with the next step? :-)

Kind regards

**EDIT: MY FUNCTION RIGHT NOW:**

```
def personInCountry(data)
    newdic = {}
    for dic in data:
        for country in dic['country']:
            if not country in newdic:
               newdic[country] = []
            newdic[country].append('{} {}'.format(dic['fname'], dic['lname']))

    for k, v in newdic.items():
        print('{}: {}'.format(k, ', '.join(sorted(v, key=lambda x: x.split( [-1]))))
```

And when I run the function with print (the may not be in the function), the output is:

```
print(person_to_string(data))
['England: John Doe, John Foo', 'Germany: Jane Bar, John Foo, Jane Smith']
```

and I want the print of the function to be:

```
print(personInCountry(data))

TU Wien: John Doe, John Foo
University of Vienna: Jane Bar, John Foo, Jane Smith
```

What is the next step for solving this? :-)

Comment: Sure there's many solutions.

Depending on how uncertain what you want is/how flexible you expect the solution needing to be you may want to consider using Pandas ... if you're practising basic Python data structures (or for some other reason) as you started off, the above flavour can be a better match.

If known, what are the preferences in this regard?

Comment: Preferably, I would not use pandas right now. Trying to learn the basics :-)

Comment: Terminology note: that is a *list* not an array

Answer (score 1):

Just loop and collect the names

```
from collections import defaultdict

holder = defaultdict(list)
data = [
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Doe",
    "country" : [ "England" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Smith",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Foo",
    "country" : [ "England", "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Bar",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  }
]

for d in data:
  for c in d['country']:
    holder[c].append(d["fname"] + ' ' +  d["lname"])
for k,v in holder.items():
  print(f'{k}: {", ".join(v)}')
```

output

```
England: John Doe, John Foo
Germany: Jane Smith, John Foo, Jane Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple to just loop over the data, generating a new dictionary keyed by country with names in a list:

```
data = [
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Doe",
    "country" : [ "England" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Smith",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "John",
    "lname"  : "Foo",
    "country" : [ "England", "Germany" ]
  },
  {
    "fname" : "Jane",
    "lname"  : "Bar",
    "country" : [ "Germany" ]
  }
]

newdic = {}
for dic in data:
    for country in dic['country']:
        if not country in newdic:
            newdic[country] = []
        newdic[country].append('{} {}'.format(dic['fname'], dic['lname']))

print(newdic)
# {'England': ['John Doe', 'John Foo'], 'Germany': ['Jane Smith', 'John Foo', 'Jane Bar']}
```

You can then choose how to sort/output this data - e.g. to sort the names by surname:

```
for k, v in newdic.items():
    print('{}: {}'.format(k, ', '.join(sorted(v, key=lambda x: x.split()[-1]))))

# England: John Doe, John Foo
# Germany: Jane Bar, John Foo, Jane Smith
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how to get the exact output like: 
```
England: John Doe, John Foo \n

Germany: Jane Smith, John Foo, Jane Bar
```

Comment: I have added a sort filter to sort by surname

Comment: You're the best!

Comment: If this answer works for you, please vote/accept it - thanks!

Comment: @match, it's kinda inefficient though, better to join string on last step to not split it for sorting.

Comment: @match, I've meant something like [this](https://tio.run/##pZJNa8MwDIbv/hXGJxtCYewyCr2MfcCuO4YwTKO03mLJOO5GKP3tmZ20dQ776JgPPuiVnle25PqwJby@cX4YGk@WkwOvA3lurCMfuAlgNxACeMZqHTRf8ZLxePbjnY5oUFsQSy6eaIuiyEJ7Eu4I5vE17TD4PiqluMdNq7EW1Sgfir/DH4h@gxdcPIK3GvsLfDTClz7P1oTtd07/x99qfyGcVYwhfNRmHaexP7BEeJmGFAN5YvLoWpxcFGviZFOdQZ6muRyBKXi0GwWzLs/21fLcUkJE/sxNxlR11k0zp0wN5uqRMMbKY1a10M4B1jIRMwbaDn4sSyuYSuIvpM4dkGshWy7edbuDTqr8OFPELN8RpizAnU07DrKLCw61nAAFf4N@Nfu8K6VU7mNKKk1yF1wsXsmgnKCKMecNBjn5q2H4BA). It will demonstrate 5-10% better performance *(tested)*.

Answer (score 0):

This is an update of [match's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011945/10824407) which makes it 10% more efficient. Code:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [ ... ]

newdic = {}
name_getter = itemgetter("fname", "lname")
for dic in data:
    for country in dic["country"]:
        name = name_getter(dic)
        if country in newdic:
            newdic[country].append(name)
        else:
            newdic[country] = [name]

for people in newdic.values():
    for i, person in enumerate(sorted(people, key=itemgetter(1))):
        people[i] = " ".join(person)

print(newdic)
```

The main difference is that in this method I join strings after sorting happened which makes sorting faster.